# Angular: Dynamic configuration during deploy

Tags: angular, dynamic-variables, formio

I am using the Formio library for dynamic form management. I have successfully deployed an application using docker. Currently, I want to deploy in multiple environments but still use the same repository, only changing some variables like apiUrl, appUrl.

app.modules.ts

```
import { AppConfig } from './config';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    {provide: FormioAppConfig, useValue: AppConfig},
    {provide: FormioAuthConfig, useValue: {
      login: {
        form: 'user/login'
      },
      register: {
        form: 'user/register'
      }
    }}
  ]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is something I want to change in each environment during deploy. For example, for a `test` environment I want apiUrl to be test-api.com, and corresponding to `dev` environment is dev-api.com (config.ts)

```
export const AppConfig = {
  appUrl: "${API_GATEWAY}",
  apiUrl: "${API_GATEWAY}"
};
```

I tried adding an environment variable when running the `docker run` command and then using the `sed` command to replace the API path. I get the following error

```
main-es2020.947b80c351d74b4ef290.js:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```